# How to make all values write to DataGrid

Tags: c#

I have a few questions:

1. How to fix the error clear_click;
   Error Code CS0103 C # The name 'list' does not exist in the current context
2. How to make a conclusion of my calculations?

I did not find the answers to my questions.

```cs
private void clear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
    list.Clear();
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = list;
}

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    double a = 0.1;
    double b = 1.0;
    double n = 140.0;
    double h = (b - a) / 10.0;
    double s = 0, y = 0;
    for (double x = a; x <= b; x += h)
    {
        s += 1 + 3 * Math.Pow(x, 2);
    }
    DataGridTextColumn c1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
    c1.Header = "№";
    c1.Binding = new Binding("id");
    c1.Width = 50;
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(c1);
    DataGridTextColumn c2 = new DataGridTextColumn
    {
        Header = "x",
        Binding = new Binding("x"),
        Width = 100
    };
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(c2);
    DataGridTextColumn c3 = new DataGridTextColumn();
    c3.Header = "Y";
    c3.Binding = new Binding("Y");
    c3.Width = 100;
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(c3);
    DataGridTextColumn c4 = new DataGridTextColumn();
    c4.Header = "S";
    c4.Binding = new Binding("S");
    c4.Width = 100;
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(c4);
    DataGridTextColumn c5 = new DataGridTextColumn();
    c5.Header = "Y";
    c5.Binding = new Binding("Y");
    c5.Width = 100;
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(c5);
    row newRow = new row();
    newRow.id = 0;
    newRow.x = 1;
    newRow.Y = 1000;
    newRow.S = 1001;
    newRow.eps = 1;
    List<row> list = new List<row>();
    list.Add(newRow);
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = list;
}
```

Comment: "*How to make a conclusion...*" is too vague to even guess at. But the other problem is [a scoping problem](https://www.devu.com/tutorials/cs-asp/articles/lesson-24-understanding-variable-scope)

Answer (score 0):

> The name 'list' does not exist in the current context

Because it doesn't exist in that context.  Within that method or any containing scope there is no variable called `list`.  You have a variable called `list` in a *different* method, but it's local to only that method.

If `list` should be available in multiple methods of that class, make it a class-level variable:

```
List<row> list = new List<row>();

private void clear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //...
    list.Clear();
    //...
}

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //...
    newRow.eps = 1;
    list.Add(newRow);
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = list;
}
```

While it's not clear what else you're asking, this *might* also solve your problem of "How to make all values write to DataGrid".  In your current code every time you invoke `button_Click` you create an entirely new list, add *one* element to it, and bind that list of one element to the grid.  But by making the list a class-level instance with a scope outside that one method, every time you invoke `button_Click` you add another new element to the same list.  So every click would (should) add a row to the grid.

Comment: Thanks for helping us clean the dataGrid. Yes, when you click button_click the grid creates another one. And how to write the data to be recorded? How to make the creation of a grid for a button, so as not to build a grid every time you click?

Comment: @JZ_52: *"how to write the data to be recorded?"* - It's not clear what you're asking or how it relates to the question above.  Please be specific about what isn't working in a particular operation in your code.

Comment: I have a task:
Displays the values of the functions Y (x) and its expansions into the series S (x) for x, varying with the step h = (b - a) / 10.
a = 0.1, b = 1.0, n = 140, S (x) = 1 + 3 * x ^ 2 + ... + 2n + 1 / n! * x ^ 2n

This solution is S (x) = s += 1 + 3 * Math.Pow(x, 2) And I want to withdraw it.